# Send Image to the API using image path that stored in local database

Tags: api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

> I am trying to send image to the API, I have multiple local storage image path which is stored in local
> database sqlite and I have to upload these image on one click. in the
> local database. replace `_mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync`
> with `_mediaFile = Image_Path_From_Database`
> The **datatobesync** it contain multiple local storage image path from local dat

conn = await DependencyService.Get().GetConnection();
List datatobesync = new List();

```
                    datatobesync = (from c in conn.Table<CDCInfo>()
                                    where c.SyncStatus == 0 && c.UserName == Settings.Username
                                    select new CDCInfo
                                    {
                                         PhotoPath = c.PhotoPath,
                                    }
```

> I have a string image path but I am not sure about how
> to use this
>
> Using MediaPlugin for opening a gallery or camera. After selecting the
> picture I set that picture to _mediafile and added to the content and send it to the API.
> `Detail` [Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/messages/14876/#Item_6)

> these lines of code gets image from the gallery or camra (using MediaPlugin) in a
> mediaFile and send it to the API

```
private MediaFile _mediaFile;
        _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.
    StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Sample",
                    Name = "test.jpg",
                    AllowCropping = true,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
                });
         var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),"\"Files\"", $"\"{_mediaFile.path}\"");
        var httpClnt = new HttpClient();
        result = await httpClnt.PostAsync(Urle, content);
```

**How can I add image to the content using database path** and send it to the API without using MediaPlugin.
**I am trying to do something like**

```
 foreach (var item in datatobesync)
                { 
                    try
                    {    
                        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                        MultipartFormDataContent content = new  
                                                 MultipartFormDataContent(); 
                       content.Add(new 
                       StreamContent("Here I want to user item.PhotoPath Image path from the database".GetStream()),"\"Files\"", 
                     $"\"{item.PhotoPath}\"");
                        var httpClnt = new HttpClient();
                        result = await httpClnt.PostAsync(Urle, content);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

> I dont know how to use image path at this line

```
content.Add(new StreamContent(How_to_User_ImagePath_Her.GetStream()),"\"Files\"", 
                         $"\"{item.PhotoPath}\"");
```

> How to get `GetStram()`  of image path

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: if you are just asking "how do I create a stream from a file path?" then there are dozens of existing questions that show how to do this

Comment: main point is how to send image to the API using image path from the local database in other questions or examples they use 'TakePhotoAsync' or 'PickPhotoAsync' to get image from gallery or camra but I want to use image path which is stored in local database and store it in a mediafile to get the stream and send it to the server